# ReactJS how to create list "ol" or "ul" with roman number format

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flux, roman-numerals

I'm creating JSX element which contains list, and I need to use the roman format, but nothing work

1. type='i' not defined
2. data-type='i' not working
3. list-style-type="upper-roman" not working

   ```
   const howToTest: JSX.Element = (    
     <div>
       <ol list-style-type="upper-roman">
         <li>1</li>
       </ol>
     </div>
   );
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not pass `list-style-type` as a prop but as a `style` property.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ol style={{ listStyleType: "upper-roman" }}>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```